# Multipatch georeferencing in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: georeferencing, arcgis-pro, multipatch

I am currently using ArcGIS Pro to create a 3D campus model and I have floor plans extruded by each individual floor to represent buildings. Another group is working on the modeling side of things and have multipatch features (.shp) that they have created, but there are a lot of issues that arise when trying to bring them into ArcGIS Pro. First they are not georeferenced, so we have to find them wherever they end up (usually at 0,0 in the center of the globe) and then when we get them to fit (this is done manually).

Does anyone know of a more automatic way to get these multipatches georeferenced with a more automatic method?

Comment: "Another group is working on the modeling side of things and have multipatch features (.shp) that they have created" - how precisely did they create these i.e. what does one of these "shapefiles" look like?